# Html fetching facebook User URL but iFrame not fetching the User Url to the specified field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I have an Facebook invitation form, It works like this : When someone invite 5 users from Facebook there is a content box unlocks with a URL field(iFrame) containing the sender user facebook URL. But rightnow it is not working i mean the url is no receiving by the filed(iFrame). But in case of iFrame when i use HTML code it works. But html doesn't satisfy me 100%. So i need those iFrame to work somehow. Can somebody help me with ?